# Performance problems with Linq To CSV

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq, ienumerable

I have found a library which connects csv-files with linq. I understood the principles and my code works well. But i have some problems with big csv files.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library

Now i want to access specific single items from my _dataTable object. I get them like this:

```
public class CsvFile
{  
    private IEnumerable<DataRow> _dataTable = cc.Read<DataRow>(_filePath, _inputFileDescription);
    public string GetItem(int row, int column)
    {
        return _dataTable.ElementAt<DataRow>(row).ElementAt<DataRowItem>(column).Value;
    }
}
```

When i now call the method like this in a loop:

```
CsvFile file1 = new CsvFile("C:\\dev_csvcompare\\Master.csv", ';', true);
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        string dummy = file1.GetItem(1, i);  //Does not make sense, my loop is a bit more complicated
    }
```

it gets very slow, because the IEnumerable opens the stream every call.

In the documentation([link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library)) under "Deferred Reading" they say i can access the ienumerable "_dataTable" with a foreach loop (this does work fine), but this is in my case no option because i want access to specific items in the csv.

Are there possibilities to keep the filestream open so that the performace increases?

EDIT (My code, maybe a lot of nosense, im not so experienced with .net, c# and oop):

```
    public void Compare(int key1, int key2, int col1, int col2)
            {
                string lastKeyCol1 = null;
                string lastKeyCol2 = null;

                List<string> sortedKeyColFile1 = new List<string>();
                List<string> sortedKeyColFile2 = new List<string>();

                int file1counter = 0;
                int file2counter = 0;

                int cnt = 0;

                sortedKeyColFile1 = _file1.GetCol(key1);
                sortedKeyColFile1.Sort();

                sortedKeyColFile2 = _file2.GetCol(key2);
                sortedKeyColFile2.Sort();

                while ((file1counter < sortedKeyColFile1.Count) || (file2counter < sortedKeyColFile2.Count))
                {
                    _outputList.Add(new OutputValues(key1, key2, col1, col2));
                    //Keys are in both files
                    if (sortedKeyColFile1[file1counter] == sortedKeyColFile2[file2counter])
                    {                   
                        if (lastKeyCol1 == sortedKeyColFile1[file1counter])
                        {
                            //Keys are redundant
                            _outputList[cnt].RedundantKeyF1 = true;
                        }               
                        if (lastKeyCol2 == sortedKeyColFile2[file2counter])
                        {
                            //Keys are redundant
                            _outputList[cnt].RedundantKeyF2 = true;
                        }
                        lastKeyCol1 = sortedKeyColFile1[file1counter];
                        lastKeyCol2 = sortedKeyColFile2[file2counter];

                        _outputList[cnt].ValF1 = _file1.GetItem(file1counter, col1);
                        _outputList[cnt].ValF2 = _file2.GetItem(file2counter, col2);
                        _outputList[cnt].LineNumF1 = file1counter;
                        _outputList[cnt].LineNumF2 = file2counter;

                        //compare the values (because keys do match at this place)
                        _outputList[cnt].CompareResult = CompareString(_file1.GetItem(file1counter, col1), _file2.GetItem(file2counter, col2));

                        if (file1counter < sortedKeyColFile1.Count)
                        {
                            file1counter++;
                        }
                        if (file2counter < sortedKeyColFile2.Count)
                        {
                            file2counter++;
                        }
                    }
                    //Key sortedKeyColFile2[file2counter] is not in file 1
                    else if (file2counter < sortedKeyColFile2.Count && 0 < (string.Compare(sortedKeyColFile1[file1counter], sortedKeyColFile2[file2counter])))
                    {
                        _outputList[cnt].LineNumF2 = file2counter;
                        if (lastKeyCol2 == sortedKeyColFile2[file2counter])
                        {
                            //Keys are redundant
                            _outputList[cnt].RedundantKeyF2 = true;
                        }
                        lastKeyCol2 = sortedKeyColFile2[file2counter];
                        file2counter++;
                    }
                    //Key sortedKeyColFile1[file1counter] is not in file 2
                    else if (file1counter < sortedKeyColFile1.Count)
                    {
                        _outputList[cnt].LineNumF1 = file1counter;
                        if (lastKeyCol1 == sortedKeyColFile1[file1counter])
                        {
                            //Keys are redundant
                            _outputList[cnt].RedundantKeyF1 = true;
                        }
                        lastKeyCol1 = sortedKeyColFile1[file1counter];
                        file1counter++;
                    }
                    cnt++;
                }
            }

//And here the important part of the csv-file class, maybe not so interesting
    public class CsvFile
    {
        private string _filePath = null;
        private char _separator = ',';
        private bool _hasHeader = true;
        private CsvContext _cc = null;
        private CsvFileDescription _inputFileDescription = null;
        private List<string> _headers = null;
        private IEnumerable<DataRow> _dataTable = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor for a new CsvFile object. 
        /// The Constructor initiates the Object and read the values out of the File
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filePath">Full path of the csv-file</param>
        /// <param name="separator">Seperator of the csv-file, eg: ';' or ',' or '\t'</param>
        /// <param name="hasHeader">Is true if the first col of the csv-file contains a headers</param>
        public CsvFile(string filePath, char separator, bool hasHeader = true)
        {
            //Throws an exception if something is wrong with the file
            File.OpenRead(filePath);

            _filePath = filePath;
            _separator = separator;
            _hasHeader = hasHeader;
            _cc = new CsvContext();
            _inputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
            {
                SeparatorChar = separator,
                FirstLineHasColumnNames = hasHeader
            };

            _dataTable = _cc.Read<DataRow>(_filePath, _inputFileDescription);

            if (hasHeader)
            {
                ParseHeaders();
            }
        }
        public List<string> GetCol(int col)
        {
            List<string> column = new List<string>();
            int cnt = 0;
            foreach(DataRow x in _dataTable)
            {
                column.Add(x[col].Value);
                cnt++;
            }
            return column;
        }
        private void ParseHeaders()
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(_filePath);
            if (!file.EndOfStream)
            {
                //_headers = file.ReadLine().Split(_separator);

                _headers = new List<string> (file.ReadLine().Split(_separator));
            }
            file.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The only way to keep the stream open is to do this as part of a single read, from beginning to end. You need to optimize the code you did not post to work with the file. To help with that, we need to see that code.

Comment: `IEnumerable` is an interface, it can't be slow or fast.

Comment: Why don't you use: `return _dataTable[row][column].Value` Because now you will access the datatable as enumerable, this will lead to a full _table scan_ every lookup. This is the same with the columns.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen `_dataTable[row][column]` doesn't work because `_dataTable` is a badly named `IEnumerable<>`

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM Is that my issue or the issue of the library?

Comment: Try calling `ToList()` on the original result from Read.  This will store the entire parsed file in memory so that subsequent random accesses don't need to load the file again.

Comment: This is for sure a possibility, but it loads everything in the memory and then the library is completly unnecessary. I could just open a stream and do the same

Comment: Why not do the foreach directly? foreach(var row in _dataTable) { foreach (var field in row) { DoStuff(); } }, I didn't noticed the IEnumerable before. You should iterate the _dataTable ones (every time you touch the _dataTable, it will create a new Enumerator struct and it will start over at the first row.

Comment: [Click here for complete LINQ example in Asp.net 4.0](http://problemaspdotnet.blogspot.in/2014/02/linq-example-in-aspnet.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class CsvFile
{  
    private IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = cc.Read<DataRow>(_filePath, _inputFileDescription);
    //...       
    public IEnumerable<DataRow> Rows { get { return rows; } }

}
```

And then:

```
CsvFile file1 = new CsvFile("C:\\dev_csvcompare\\Master.csv", ';', true);
foreach(DataRow row in file1.Rows)
{
    string dummy = row[1];
}
```